# GCP App Engine Firewall not reflected on GCP console when applied using terraform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am using terraform to import the state of existing `GCP App Engine Resource firewall rules` so that the firewall rules can be later managed with `terraform` . Also planning to add one more additional rule on top of it with `priority 999`.

I imported using below command

```
terraform import google_app_engine_firewall_rule.newrule <project>/1000
```

After that I executed `terraform show` to identify the state of existing resources and created `main.tf` from it. My existing rules are as follows

```
 PRIORITY    ACTION     SOURCE_RANGE          DESCRIPTION
 1000        DENY     X.X.X.X/32
 2147483647  ALLOW           *                 The default action.
```

After adding the information of new firewall in `main.tf` , the file looks as below

```
  # google_app_engine_firewall_rule.default:
  resource "google_app_engine_firewall_rule" "default" {
    action       = "ALLOW"
    description  = "The default action."
    priority     = 2147483647
    project      = "<<project>>"
    source_range = "*"

  timeouts {}
 }

 # google_app_engine_firewall_rule.newrule:
 resource "google_app_engine_firewall_rule" "newrule" {
     action       = "DENY"
     priority     = 1000
     project      = "<<project>>"
     source_range = "X.X.X.X/32"

      timeouts {}
    }

 resource "google_app_engine_firewall_rule" "newrule1" {
     action       = "DENY"
     priority     = 999
     project      = "<<project>>"
     source_range = "X.X.X.X/32"

     timeouts {}
   }
```

`terraform plan` showed no error and `terraform apply` executed successfully . Validating with `gcloud` command looks the rule is added successfully . The first rule from below output with `priority 999.`

```
    $ gcloud app firewall-rules list
     PRIORITY    ACTION  SOURCE_RANGE           DESCRIPTION
     999         DENY    X.X.X.X/32
     1000        DENY    X.X.X.X/32
    2147483647   ALLOW       *                 The default action.
```

But when I check it from front end using `GCP-console` , I cannot find the rule . It is still showing the old rules.

```
   PRIORITY     ACTION  SOURCE_RANGE           DESCRIPTION
     1000        DENY    X.X.X.X/32
    2147483647   ALLOW       *                 The default action.
```

Please clarify on this behaviour.

Comment: Please, let me know which `glcoud` command you use to validate the output.

Comment: `gcloud app firewall-rules list` is the command

Comment: Question, the IP address of X.X.X.X is the same for `newrule` and `newrule1`

Comment: They are different

Comment: Sorry , I think it takes time to get the rules reflected in the GUI . I checked the console again today and now the rules are there . So there is a  time gap to update the firewall change in GUI but not sure how much time it takes to get the rules reflected in GUI

Comment: Okay, no issues. I was not able to reproduce your issue. But now I understand that everything is fine. Glad to hear!

Comment: I would suggest to post that comment as an answer as others can benefit from that. I'll upvote it

Comment: Thanks for looking into it . I will post an answer to it as per your suggestion. Also will try the same exercise again if i came across similar lag issues and the time gap for `GUI Console` update after executing `terraform` apply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to  be related with `browser` refresh . I was browsing between different menu items from `App Engine Dashboard` thinking that it will refresh the `firewall` page too but that is not the case . When I refreshed it from the `browser` , the new `firewall rules` are reflected .

Also , when I add a new firewall rule using `gcloud` command as shown below , in order to get it reflected in the `GUI Console` , I need to do a `browser refresh`

```
  gcloud app firewall-rules create 997 --action=allow --source-range=35.X.X.X/32
```

May be a refresh button in the `GUI` will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

When I applied your main.tf file in the Cloud Shell with `terraform apply` it showed me the following error

```
Error: Error creating FirewallRule: googleapi: Error 400: Cannot add rule at priority 2147483647. The priority for new rules must be less than the priority 2
147483647 for the Default Action.
```

When I changed the priority to 147483646 it was successfully applied.

Comment: Rule 1000 ,2147483647 are already added manually . Now further new addition of rules will be managed by `terraform`  . So  added rule for 999 in `main.tf` and then applied `terraform plan` . No errors and rule is applied successfully and `gcloud` is showing the new rule listed. But in GCP console it is still showing the earlier rules which are added manually . So there is a discrepancy between `gcloud` and 'GIU console' output for the firewall rules